# how to get what api published, subscribed by a user in wso2 using admin service

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is there any admin service similar to RemoteUserStoreManagerService present in wso2 apim 1.10 to get information about what api is published by a particular user and what api he is subscribed?

I know we can get this information from database, but I want to use admin service.

Thanks,
Santosh

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Store Jaggery APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Store+APIs) in APIM 1.10.0 for this.

**To get all APIs created by user `john`.**

1) Login as `admin` user (or any other user who has both publisher and store access)

```
curl -X POST -c cookies http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag -d 'action=login&username=admin&password=admin'
```

2) Search for APIs published by `john`.

```
curl -X POST -b cookies "http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/search/api-search/ajax/search.jag" -d "action=searchAPIs&query=provider:john&start=0&end=3"
```

**To get all APIs subscribed by user `john`**

1) Login as user `john`.

```
curl -X POST -c cookies http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag -d 'action=login&username=john&password=pass'
```

2) Get all subscriptions

```
curl -b cookies http://localhost:9763/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-list/ajax/subscription-list.jag?action=getAllSubscriptions
```